# drop down menu on image button on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner

what i have is an action bar .. and i have only logo in it and an image button and i want when i press on the button a spinner with a three values will appear and each one of them open a new activity , here is my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    android.app.ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
     // i want the spinner to be add here 
        }
    });

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int arg0, long arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ublic class MainActivity extends Activity{
...
...

```
/**
 * On selecting action bar icons
 * */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        // search action
        return true;
    case R.id.action_location_found:
        // location found
        LocationFound();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_refresh:
        // refresh
        return true;
    case R.id.action_help:
        // help action
        return true;
    case R.id.action_check_updates:
        // check for updates action
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**
 * Launching new activity
 * */
private void LocationFound() {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationFound.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

Try This code :

For better understanding go through following link
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Comment: this is a spinner that does not start from an image button .. its only a spinner with a 3 value and the first value will always will be displayed .. so how can i do that?

Comment: I have changed code...try now...
Please go through this lnk  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Comment: you are just copying the code .. this is not what i need

Comment: Download the project from that link...you will all the detail